# Spelling Suggestor in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, .net, spelling

I need to build a spelling suggestor in ASP.NET... The below are my requirement.

Case 1:  My list of words are not just englist words but will also includes some codes like AACD, ESSA, BIMER etc... I may provide such (New) words from Database.

Case 2:  I also need a similar spelling suggestor for Non-English Language,  Even here, I can provide a list of words from a Database.

Now, Any suggestions as to how I implement the same is welcome.

Further, I found the following Python Code, from a website, which states it returns the most probable suggestion (in english ofcourse).  If someone can translate it into C# that would be really helpful.

```
 import re, collections
    def words(text): return re.findall('[a-z]+', text.lower()) 
    def train(features):  
        model = collections.defaultdict(lambda: 1) 
         for f in features:  
            model[f] += 1
        return model
    NWORDS = train(words(file('big.txt').read()))
    alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
    def edits1(word):
        s = [(word[:i], word[i:]) for i in range(len(word) + 1)]   
        deletes    = [a + b[1:] for a, b in s if b] 
        transposes = [a + b[1] + b[0] + b[2:] for a, b in s if len(b)>1]
        replaces   = [a + c + b[1:] for a, b in s for c in alphabet if b]   
        inserts    = [a + c + b     for a, b in s for c in alphabet]   
    return set(deletes + transposes + replaces + inserts)
    def known_edits2(word):    
        return set(e2 for e1 in edits1(word) for e2 in edits1(e1) if e2 in NWORDS)

    def known(words): return set(w for w in words if w in NWORDS)
    def correct(word):    
        candidates = known([word]) or known(edits1(word)) or known_edits2(word) or [word]
        return max(candidates, key=NWORDS.get)
```

Thanks
- Raja

Comment: We Need to call the method Correct("speling"), which returns String "Spelling" as most probable suggestion.

Comment: Hi, Someone there voted me down, Could you please let me know why?

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are because you've not made any effort to translate the code yourself. SO is here to help with programming problems, not to do the entirety of the work for you. In any event, if you want Norvig's spelling corrector in C#, see his original page. There are links at the bottom to folks who have translated his original code: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Comment: I voted you down because you're basically asking other people to do your work. +1 for the cheek, -2 for the wrong place to be cheeky :)

Comment: Hi all, Sorry if the question sounded that way.  I don't know python and as a result was not able to understand the head and tail of the code...  I started reading the page down to understand the concept, but more of python code made things go over my head.  Since my problem is very much similar to the one there, I just posted the code so that some one will lead me in the right direction...   Of course, my fault, I have not seen the bottom of the page...  Once again sorry, for what I sounded like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commercial product I work on uses [NETSpell Spell Checker](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/string/netspell.aspx), it has a dictionary tool that allows you to add custom dictionaries and words.

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is [NHunspel](http://nhunspell.sourceforge.net/)

> NHunspell is a free open source spell
>   checker for the .NET Framework. C# and
>   Visual Basic sample code is available
>   for spell checking, hyphenation and
>   sysnonym lookup via thesaurus.

```
using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_us.dic"))
{
    bool correct = hunspell.Spell("Recommendation");
    var suggestions = hunspell.Suggest("Recommendatio");
    foreach (string suggestion in suggestions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Suggestion is: " + suggestion );
    }
}
```

Comment: NHunspell + the [Firefox's US English spellcheck dictionary](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/united-states-english-spellche/) was perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Free .NET spell checker based around a WPF text box that can be used client or server side can be seen [here](https://github.com/aranm/SpellChecker). This can be passed a list of words to ignore (your custom dictionary)

Full disclosure...written by yours truly with some help from stack overflow of course :)